# How to resample, and create a time series of value_counts() and count() on multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Client_Id       Date    Age_Group      Gender
0      579427 2020-02-01     Under 65  Female    
1      579464 2020-02-01     Under 65  Female    
2      579440 2020-02-01     Under 65  Male      
3      579470 2020-02-01      75 - 79  Female    
4      579489 2020-02-01      75 - 79  Female    
5      579424 2020-02-01      75 - 79  Male      
6      579492 2020-02-01      75 - 79  Male      
7      579552 2020-02-01      75 - 79  Male      
8      579439 2020-02-01      80 - 84  Male      
9      579445 2020-03-01      80 - 84  Female    
10     579496 2020-03-01      80 - 84  Female    
11     579569 2020-03-01      80 - 84  Male      
12     579610 2020-03-01      80 - 84  Male      
13     579450 2020-03-01      80 - 84  Female    
14     579423 2020-03-01  85 and over  Female    
15     579428 2020-03-01  85 and over  Male
```

I am trying to resample, and get a time series of count of `Client_Id`, count of `Gender`, and count  of `Age_Group`.

For example, I can get `value_counts` of Gender:

```
df.set_index('Date').resample('D')['Gender'].value_counts()

Date        Gender    
2020-02-01  Male          5
            Female        4
2020-03-01  Female        4
            Male          3
```

I can also get `value_counts` for Age_Group.

And I can get number of clients per day:

```
df.set_index('Date').resample('D')['Client_Id'].count()

Date
2020-01-02    9
2020-01-03    7
```

However I would like to all outputs to be one dataframe, with the result of the value counts as their own column.

I have managed to do it, like this:

[image]

However the code is VERY ugly. I also have more column to process, and I would prefer not to have such a long chain of `merge`.

This is what I've done, using `unstack` and `merge`:

```
(df.set_index('Date').resample('D')['Client_Id'].count().to_frame()
 .merge(df.set_index('Date').resample('D')['Gender'].value_counts().unstack(), left_index=True, right_index=True)
 .merge(df.set_index('Date').resample('D')['Age_Group'].value_counts().unstack(), left_index=True, right_index=True))
```

Is there an easier / more tidy / built in way to do this?

My dataframe as a dict:

```
{'Client_Id': {0: 579427,
  1: 579464,
  2: 579440,
  3: 579470,
  4: 579489,
  5: 579424,
  6: 579492,
  7: 579552,
  8: 579439,
  9: 579445,
  10: 579496,
  11: 579569,
  12: 579610,
  13: 579450,
  14: 579423,
  15: 579428},
 'Date': {0: Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2020-01-03 00:00:00'),
  10: Timestamp('2020-01-03 00:00:00'),
  11: Timestamp('2020-01-03 00:00:00'),
  12: Timestamp('2020-01-03 00:00:00'),
  13: Timestamp('2020-01-03 00:00:00'),
  14: Timestamp('2020-01-03 00:00:00'),
  15: Timestamp('2020-01-03 00:00:00')},
 'Age_Group': {0: 'Under 65',
  1: 'Under 65',
  2: 'Under 65',
  3: '75 - 79',
  4: '75 - 79',
  5: '75 - 79',
  6: '75 - 79',
  7: '75 - 79',
  8: '80 - 84',
  9: '80 - 84',
  10: '80 - 84',
  11: '80 - 84',
  12: '80 - 84',
  13: '80 - 84',
  14: '85 and over',
  15: '85 and over'},
 'Gender': {0: 'Female    ',
  1: 'Female    ',
  2: 'Male      ',
  3: 'Female    ',
  4: 'Female    ',
  5: 'Male      ',
  6: 'Male      ',
  7: 'Male      ',
  8: 'Male      ',
  9: 'Female    ',
  10: 'Female    ',
  11: 'Male      ',
  12: 'Male      ',
  13: 'Female    ',
  14: 'Female    ',
  15: 'Male      '}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for `DatetimeIndex` in `df1`, so possible use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('Date').resample('D')['Gender'].value_counts().unstack()
df2 = df.set_index('Date').resample('D')['Client_Id'].count()
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```